# Accessing the internal xml structure of an excel file

Tags: c#, xml, excel

First I have to say that I am not a profound `c#` coder. I read in a post that it is possible to access the internal xml structure in an excel file.

My question is:

Can this only be done via `c#` or is this also possible via `java`?
How can this be accomplished in `c#`?

I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done using [OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Comment: I personally have had better experiences with EPPlus.

Comment: @ta.speot.is There are some good libraries but the question is about accessing raw xml structure. OpenXML SDK is the most "low-level" library to use with .xlsx files.

Comment: The most "low-level" would be http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx since they're just xml files inside a zip file (give or take).

Comment: Yes, that's true. You have to unzip .xlsx package before using XmlReader or whatever to parse xml.

Comment: Or just get the data as a `Stream` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx

Comment: Is it also possible to access this xml files without coding? Like just unziping them? I would like to have an example of such an xml file?

Comment: @Vivien You can use archivation software like WinRAR to unzip an .xlsx file.